# Calculating average for a row in one record with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table with 4 columns, "first, second, third, and average". They are points of each user scores in 3 tries, and then calculate the average score of 3 tries, and enter the computed result into "average" column. How can I achieve this on the server side with rails since user can turn off javascript on the client side?

Thank you for your help in advance!
(rails 5.0.1.0, postgresql 9.5, ruby 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand from your question, it seems to me that you cannot wait for the user to complete the tries to send them, I would suggest and the start of the user attempt create a record with an ID in that table to keep track that the user is "trying" after each individual try send through a rest service the result of each try with the attempt ID and add it to the existing record, once he has done the final try you can easily calculate the average, if the user turns off the JS at any given moment you have an existing instance in you DB of the user attempt and you can act from there. Let me know if there's anything i'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to store it, just calculate on final submission:

```
params[:average] = (params[:first].to_i + params[:second].to_i + params[:third].to_i)/3.0
```

If you're fine with just calculating it, you could do it in sql with something like:

```
select id, (select avg(c) from (values(first),(second),(third)) table(c)) as average from table;
```

But probably better to avoid that and just store it when updating.